# How can we use promise in node.js packages

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, package

When we write a module for node.js, we use callback functions. I learned promises in javascript and I want to use in node.js module. Can we use promises instead of callback functions ? if we can, how ?

note : via function in node module file ( you know exports.some_func ) , we do somethings and we can send back informations with callback . Can we use promise instead of that callback ?

Comment: Start with `Promise.resolve` and a good tutorial on thenables...

Comment: Your question is a big vague. Do you want to call `Promise.then` on existing functions like `require('fs').readFileAsync` or do you want to write your own `Promise`s?

Comment: via function in node module file ( you know `exports.some_func` ) , we do somethings and we can send back informations with callback . Can we use promise instead of that callback ?

Comment: Sounds like you want to wrap callbacks in a promise. That can be done easily with the Q library. Take a look at https://strongloop.com/strongblog/promises-in-node-js-with-q-an-alternative-to-callbacks. See specifically the example on Creating raw promises.

Comment: can we send data back  with promises ?

Comment: Of course! You simply return a value!

Comment: ok thank you, but can you give me a simple example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can we use promise instead of that callback ?

Yes, rather than accepting a callback in your exported function, you can just return a promise and make sure that promise is resolved/rejected with the proper value/reason when the async operation is done.

Here's an example:

Imagine you have a module interface for reading a file, then you can have that interface return a promise like this:

```
// myFileModule.js
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports.getFile = function(filename, options) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        fs.readFile(filename, options, function(err, data) {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
}
```

The caller would then use it like this:

```
const myFiles = require('myFileModule.js');

myFiles.getFile('temp.txt').then(function(data) {
    // process data here
}, function(err) {
    // got an error here
});
```

Comment: thank you for your comment. thats grea.

Comment: @hasan - If this answers your question, then please indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn yo some reputation points for followiong the proper procedure here on stack overflow.  If it doesn't answer your question, then please explain what part of your question you still do not understand.